# Spring SecurityConfiguration

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm having a problem with this code...
When I run the application it goes to the login page instead of going to the index page.

This is my security config:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/dba/**").hasRole("DBA").and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password").and()
            .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
            .tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and().csrf().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");

}
```

I have the index file but when I put the address I have 404...

Don't get what is wrong

UPDATE
Now I have other issues.

I have changed my code to:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin*/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user*/**").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/dba*/**").hasRole("DBA").and().formLogin().loginPage("/index").permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password").and()
            .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
            .tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and().csrf().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
}
```

and start with index page, then I choose login, I put my credentials and I return to index... choosing login again I'm going to my admin page

This is my Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@SessionAttributes("roles")
public class IndexController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Atividades.class);

    @Autowired
    AtividadesService as;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    UserProfileService userProfileService;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver;


   @RequestMapping(value = { "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
        //Lista as atividades da semana
        List<Atividades> atividades = as.listAllAtividades();
        model.addAttribute("atividades", atividades);
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/admin" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(ModelMap model) {
        List<AppUser> users = userService.listAllUsers();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "/admin/admin";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("roles")
    public List<UserProfile> initializeProfiles() {
        return userProfileService.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Access_Denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String accessDeniedPage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "accessDenied";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage() {
        if (isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
            return "login";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/admin";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null){
            //new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
            persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.logout(request, response, auth);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
        }
        return "redirect:/login?logout";
    }

    private String getPrincipal(){
        String userName = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            userName = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            userName = principal.toString();
        }
        return userName;
    }

    private boolean isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous() {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication);
    }
    
}
```

I have used the debug and when I hit Login link the debugger goes to that method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage() {
    if (isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
        return "login";
    } else {
        return "redirect:/admin";
    }
}
```

And check isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous() which is null since I didn't provide any credentials.
This is happening because the main page was the login... but I wanted to have an index page with information and a link (login).

any help here?

Comment: map the index page to /

Answer (score 0):

you should add :

```
.loginPage("/login");
```

or

```
.loginPage("/index");
```

for more informations : [sprnig-doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/guides/form.html)

Comment: Please provide exact positioning of where to add this in the user's code

Comment: he can add the code after any line like `.antMatchers("/index").formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()`